# problemas con mostrar los null de una tablas

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, highcharts, chart.js

Estimados,

```
    CREATE TABLE `preguntas` (
      `id_pregunta` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `nombre` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
      `id_dimension_p` int(11) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

   CREATE TABLE `respuesta` (
  `id_respuesta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tipo_respuesta` set('1','2','3','4','5') COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_pregunta_r` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;
```

tengo esta consulta

```
SELECT preguntas.id_pregunta,respuesta.tipo_respuesta,
sum(IF (respuesta.tipo_respuesta is null ,0,1))  AS total_com
FROM preguntas 
LEFT JOIN respuesta
ON preguntas.id_pregunta=respuesta.id_pregunta_r
GROUP BY preguntas.id_pregunta,respuesta.tipo_respuesta
```

y me arroja esto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que debería arrojar

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo mostrar los nulos para poder graficar 
cualquier ayuda o orientación sera agradecida

Comment: Quieres que muestre null en caso de no haber registros?, deberias explicar un poco mas la estructura de tus tablas

Comment: eso mismo, esto es una encuesta supongamos que han respondido 4 personas con escala de likert(1=no aplica, 2= muy en desacuerdo, 3 = en desacuerdo, 4 = en acuerdo, 5 = muy en acuerdo)    
en la pregunta 1 hubo dos no aplica, uno en acuerdo, uno muy de acuerdo
necesito que me muestre así dos no aplica, cero muy en desacuerdo, cero en desacuerdo, uno en acuerdo y uno muy de acuerdo.

Comment: As tratado de quitar tu condicion en la suma?  De cuando sean valores null

Comment: si lo hice
tampoco me sale la tabla que necesito no me muestra los null

Comment: Si ya intentaste eso y tambien agruparlos solo por preguntas, seria mejor si añadieras a la pregunta la estructura de tus dos tablas.

Comment: Dale un order by respuesta.tipo_respuesta asc, para que te ordene el tipo de respuesta, y checa

Comment: Para escribirte una respuesta necesitaria que agregaras las estructuras de las 2 tablas, y algunos datos de prueba. si puedes armar un fiddle con eso mejor. Tu problema es que el left join, no va a traer registros nulos de la derecha y sumarlos. Para lo que vos queres, deberias agregar otro query sobre el que tenes, para que despues haga la suma. o unir dos querys, uno que sume lo que existe y otro que agregue lo que no existe.

Comment: ya coloque la estructura de las 2 tablas y que los datos debería poner todos pero son artos datos, pero si quieres los inserto igual.
gracias por la orientacion

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas saber la cantidad de respuestas que tienes deberias utilizar count,  la consulta qedaria asi:

```
SELECT preguntas.id_pregunta,IFNULL (respuesta.tipo_respuesta,0) AS respuesta , COUNT (respuesta.tipo_respuesta ) AS total_com FROM preguntas LEFT JOIN respuesta ON preguntas.id_pregunta=respuesta.id_pregunta_r GROUP BY preguntas.id_pregunta,respuesta.tipo_respuesta
```

Comment: Hola gracias por responder.
La consulta que me dijiste me arroja la misma tabla que tengo arriba, aun me falta que me muestre los Null para poder graficar los datos.
Saludos

Comment: Que tipo de grafico con highcharts estas utilizando? Cuando no tengas resultados,  es mejor mandar 0 q null a highcharts

Comment: estoy utilizando Stacked column 
me exprese mal si necesito que sea 0 para poder graficar.
supongamos que tengo 21 preguntas en mi encuesta.
En la consulta tiene que correr los tipo de encuesta(1=no aplica, 2= muy en desacuerdo, 3 = en desacuerdo, 4 = en acuerdo, 5 = muy en acuerdo) de cada pregunta si algún caso es 0 debería mostrarlo para tener el arreglo completo.

Comment: Edite la respuesta para el caso que no haya registros te mande 0, revisala.

Comment: aun me sigue mostrando la misma tabla que tengo arriba y he intentado de muchas formas